# Resources to learn .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

What are the best resources for a C#/.NET 2.0 developer for learning .NET 3.5? I'm struggling to learn ASP.NET MVC and I feel that a lot of my stumbling blocks have to do with not ever having explicitly studied 3.5.

Note: I know there are already these questions, but they both seem to focus on ASP.NET

- [Learning C#, ASP.NET 3.5 - what order should I learn in / what to skip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282086/learning-c-asp-net-3-5-what-order-should-i-learn-in-what-to-skip)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276229/best-book-on-aspnet-35-c-programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try browsing MSDN from [What's New in the .NET Framework Version 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332048.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

MVC has really changed the game on how everything works if you come from traditional ASP.NET Web Forms.  I would recommend the following books:

- [ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Website Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470410957)
- [Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470384611)
- [ASP.NET 3.5 Website Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470187581)

Comment: Those all look like good books. Sadly, as of today (4-16-09) none of them have been released.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend reading "C# in Depth" by Jon Skeet.  While it's focus isn't specifically the .NET framework, it gives a great overview of the changes of the C# language over time and introduces all of the new stuff in C# 3 (which overlap the .NET framework 3.5).

NOTE: Nothing specific to ASP.NET here, but again, it gives you the foundation.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Free PDF: [Free ASP.NET MVC eBook Tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx)

From the author:

> I wrote the first chapter of the book – which is a 185 page end-to-end tutorial that walks-through building a small, but complete, ASP.NET MVC application from scratch.  The agreement I made with Wrox was that I’d write it for free in return for them also making it available as a free PDF download.

Should get you started at least

Comment: Interesting that you mention it - this chapter is actually exactly what I'm doing. I'm 1/2 way through now. I'm finding though that 2.0 experience isn't enough. I'm just copying a lot of the 3.5 code without fully understanding it.